# thousands separator in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

How can I put in sql a separator in a thousands number, also 8.835.800 instead of 8835800.

Comment: That's not an SQL issue, do it in above layer.

Comment: How could we know? Which environment are you displaying your data in?

Comment: I create a report in Microsof Visual Studio. Can I configure it in SSRS

Comment: ok I got it. I used this =Replace(Format(Fields!Count.Value, "#,###0.00"),",",".")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is purely presentation matter and should be done in application layer.**

If you need to do this at database level(maybe legacy application) the solution is dependent on which RDBMS you use.

**SQL Server 2012+ [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):**

```
SELECT FORMAT(123455213.32, '###,###,###.##')
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403384)**</kbd>